# Can fotorama captions be full width with small, non-expanding images?

Tags: fotorama

Does anyone know if it's possible to set the captions on fotorama to be full width, when the images are smaller than the available space, and the images are not set to expand to fill the space?

Some of our users are uploading small images, and if data-width is constrained to the image width, then the captions are not very wide and wrap across too many lines.

Thanks ahead.